# Trouble using config.assets.precompile in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, actionview

I am trying to use the `config.assets.precompile` variable in `config/environments/production.rb` but am having troubles. I've configured it like so:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( pds.css )
```

This file is located at `app/assets/stylesheets/pds.css.scss`. I've tried deploying via capistrano and also have tried running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` but can't seem to get that file to precompile.  Here is the error I receive when trying to load a page that includes it:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (pds.css isn't precompiled):
3: <head>
4:  <meta charset="utf-8" />
5:   <title></title>
6:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "pds" %>
7:   <%= javascript_include_tag "pds" %>
8:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
9: </head>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks.  The config.assets.precompile comment was what I needed.  I had two stylesheets with conflicting styles for the body tag, that worked fine until production.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the pds.css to your application's css manifest. This is a snippet from one of my own projects:

```
/*
 * app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
 *= require_self
 *= require less
 *= require jquery.qtip.min
 *= require base
 */
```

Here base.css.sass.erb is being precompiled fine, and then included in the manifest as base.css.

And all you have to do is  include `application.css` normally in the `application.html` file.

Comment: That's certainly one way to approach it, but doesn't work in my case. pds.css/jss is for a completely separate, mobile portion of the site, so it can't be included with the rest of the css.

Embarrassingly enough, I found the problem was with my git repository. Deleting this question in order to not pollute the search results. Thanks for your help though!